# How to iterate over all entries in struct

Tags: storage

trying to iterate a multi_index struct in my contract. I can iterate it brute force like this:

```
            studentIndex students(_self, _self);
            auto itr = students.upper_bound(0);
            print("fn:",(*itr).ssn);
            print("res:",(*itr).result);
            print("equal?", itr == students.end());

            auto itr1 = itr++;
            print("fn:",(*itr1).ssn);
            print("res:",(*itr1).result);
            print("equal?", itr1 == students.end());

            auto itr2 = itr1++;
            print("fn:",(*itr2).ssn);
            print("res:",(*itr2).result);
            print("equal?", itr2 == students.end());

            auto itr3 = itr2++;
            print("fn:",(*itr3).ssn);
            print("res:",(*itr3).result);
            print("equal?", itr3 == students.end());
```

However, when I try to iterate it like this it seems to be caught in an infinite loop.

```
     for (auto itr = students.begin(); itr != students.end(); itr++) {
                print("fn:",(*itr).ssn);
                print("res:",(*itr).result);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this was an issue and it's resolved in master:
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/2787